# Dummy variables / factor variables and regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression, categories, dummy-variable

I'm currently working on data analysis regarding voting behavior: These are my two hypothesis:

H1: SVP voters in 1999, aged 18-25, who consumed more media are more likely to vote SVP in 2003.

H2: Loyal SVP voters (voted SVP in 1999 & 2003), aged 18-25, who consumed more media are likely to know more about political personalities and than about issues.

I am relatively new with R.

--> How do I create the data sample that I need: SVP voters in 1999 aged 18-25? 
 I attempted to create dummy variables for voting SVP or not in 1999 and 2003, yet I am unsure as to how I can create a sample limited to voting SVP and young age, in order to base my analysis on that population.

Below you can find what I have tried so far:

```
# Dummy creation age, voting
#age 
youngvoter99 <- ifelse(w1age>=18 & w1age<26, 1, 0)
youngvoter03 <- ifelse(w2age>=18 & w2age<30, 1, 0)
mean(w1age>=18 & w1age<26)

#voting
SVP99 <- ifelse(w111800f==4, 1, 0)
SVP03 <- ifelse(w211800f==4, 1, 0)
#Media importance
tvimportance99 <- factor(w112414,
                         levels = c("Not important at all", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Very important"))      
tvimport99low <- factor(tvimportance99,
                        levels = c("Not important at all", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"))
tvimport99high <- factor(tvimportance99,
                         levels = c("6", "7", "8", "9", "Very important")) 
str(tvimport99low)
str(tvimport99high)
--- I did the same thing for 2003 tvimportance as above 

#Categorizing  Political Knowledge

politknowhigh99 <- factor(w1soph,
                          levels = c("Low knowledge", "1", "2"))
politknowlow99 <- factor(w1soph,
                         levels = c("3", "High knowledge"))
str(politknowhigh99)
str(politknowlow99)

--- I did the same thing for 2003 politknowledge as above

#Categorizing Political Personality interest

impers99 <- factor(w112211,
                   levels = c("Very important", "Rather important", "Rather 
not important", "Not important at all"))
impers99mu <-factor(impers99, 
                    levels = c("Very important", "Rather important"))
impers99low <-factor(impers99, 
                     levels = c("Very important", "Rather important"))
str(impers99low)
str(impers99mu)

--- I did the same thing for 2003 tvimportance as above
```

--> How can I create appropriate regressions in R for Hypothesis 1/2, especially when  variables are factor variables?

I thought to create 2 linear reg. and the subtract them, however I am stuck at creating the sampled population and dealing with the factor variables. I tried working with package "plm", however it seems to be outdated for newer R studio Versions.

Comment: It would help to simplify your example code to the exact problem you are trying to solve, and to post example data.

Comment: The `plm` package should be compatible with the most recent version of R, you may just need to update your version of the package.